# Android - ProgressBar Circle with rounded tips

Tags: android, progress-bar

I know you have to do through the OnDraw drawing with canvas , but I 'm trying to use the Android ProgresBar and not with rounded tips, have used the CORNERS in SHAPES , but nothing worked.

follows the data below:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_circle"
    android:layout_width="272dp"
    android:layout_height="272dp"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/animation_center_progress"
    android:background="@drawable/animation_ring_center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="80"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
```

animation_center_progress

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="270"
android:toDegrees="270">
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.4"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="12dp"
    android:useLevel="true">

    <solid
        android:color="#FFFF8D"/>
</shape>
```

animation_ring_center

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring"
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.4"
android:thickness="12dp"
android:useLevel="false">
<solid
    android:color="#26000000"/>
```